# How to turn off airplane mode?

Tags: 11.10, wireless

I have a problem getting the WiFi to work in Ubuntu 11.10.
When I use gnome network manager it indicates that wireless is disabled by hardware switch but it is not.

In the **Network Settings** panel in the wireless section, it only shows the hardware address and the switch is off and it's disabled so that I can't change the status to On.

At the bottom there is an airplane mode switch which is On, and turning it off has no effect and it immediately turns back on.

I use a Dell Vostro 1520 laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get the bios update from dell and you will be able to enable wireless in network manager.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following in a terminal:

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

If your laptop has a hardware wifi switch, try that. Try various combinations of these.

Comment: The actual hardware switch is on as I said and none of the commands above helped. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in Debian "testing" with Gnome 3. I could not turn off the airplane mode. I have a button on my laptop which allows me to enable/disable the wireless card (Fn+F11). Hitting this button had no effect in Debian.

I have dual-boot with Ubuntu, so I booted into Ubuntu 10.10 and there the wireless was disabled as well. But, hitting the same wireless button on my laptop enabled the wireless card again. And when I booted back in Debian, wireless was working fine again.

Comment: I just started hitting fn with random fnumbers and it started working again. I think it was fn+f8 that did it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on my Dell Inspiron 6400.  Fn + F2 sorted it.  There is actually a picture of a wireless mast on the F2 key.